# SCOPE OF VARIABLE IN NEO4J - CYPHER after loading csv file. / alternate code for this pls

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So, IAM A COMPLETE NOOB and ive been struggling wiht this code, i know its a simple thing but nevertheless.

i understand that the scope of the variable changes from WITH to WITH statements, but does it also change with the where statement.? i need to return a node with the respective latitude and longitude.
i cant call the "live" variable as it isnt in scope - or so neo4j desktop says

this is my code

```
load csv with headers from "file:///latlong1.csv" as home
load csv with headers from "file:///latlong2.csv" as live
WITH point({ latitude:toFloat(home.lath), longitude:toFloat(home.longh)}) AS p1, 
 point({ latitude:toFloat(live.latl), longitude:toFloat(live.longl)}) AS p2
with toInteger(distance(p1,p2)/1000) AS km
where km > 5 
merge (redalert{dist:km, Latitude:live.latl, Longitude:live.longl})
return redalert
```

if someone could help me with an alternate modified code, it would be a blessing !

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, please edit your question and format your code so it could be more readable. Use these characters ``` at the beginning and the end of snippet. Also add some indentations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `live` in every `WITH` so that it carries forward in the query. Try this and see if it works.

```
load csv with headers from "file:///latlong1.csv" as home
load csv with headers from "file:///latlong2.csv" as live
WITH live, point({ latitude:toFloat(home.lath), longitude:toFloat(home.longh)}) AS p1, 
 point({ latitude:toFloat(live.latl), longitude:toFloat(live.longl)}) AS p2
with live, toInteger(distance(p1,p2)/1000) AS km
where km > 5 
merge (redalert{dist:km, Latitude:live.latl, Longitude:live.longl})
return redalert
```